# Studies of open source software adoption

Tags: open-source, case-studies

I'm not 100% sure this is approriate here, but I figure the area of study is particular to programmers, since it's open source software. If it's better posted somewhere else then please say so and I will post it there.

---

Can anybody point me in the right direction of any studies on businesses and consumers adopting open source software? Ideally, I'd like some qualitative information on why both parties choose (not) to adopt open source software, but raw numbers are good too.

Any relevant experiences and case studies of this from users would be welcome as well.

Comment: Questions relating to studies generally end up getting closed unless they are shown to be specifically software-development related, and unfortunately most of these sorts of questions have nowhere else to go in the Stack Exchange. Perhaps if we can get a few more people following and committing to the newly proposed [Research & Reference Finder](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38190/research-and-reference-finder) we'll have an appropriate place to ask questions such as this. (Yes, that's a hint) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to find a couple of references with regards to this.

- http://dmst.aueb.gr/dds/pubs/conf/2009-MCIS-OSSAdopt/html/SG09.htm
- [Also a reference to a similar question with some references](http://uclue.com/?xq=4853)

You can probably follow the bibliography of the on the first link to see if you can get the raw data but in general what would happen is that the companies won't discuss anything that might be seen as a competitive advantage for example: Cost savings from adopting Open Source software vs. the commercial versions, etc.

As far as the end users are concerned you would have to look for download statistics by package to actually get some sort of relevant information.